# Absolute Position Differences in iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: html, iphone, ios, css, absolute

I'm designing a responsive site ([See the site here](http://www.kent.edu/cci/comm2/)) and in the small-screen version, I'm absolutely positioning a banner (unfortunately I have no other way to manipulate the location).

On iOS7 and all modern browsers, the banner pops in to place nicely using a top: 31%

However, in iOS6, the banner appears half-way down the page (at the exact same pixel density and screen size - see [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bptsdzlwxptpt7k/Screenshot%202013-09-30%2004.24.47.png))

I can't figure out the differences between the page rendering of the two browsers.

The specific style that I'm looking at is #outerWrap h1 .

Any help would be appreciated!